# Good way to give arguments to execute Hive batch

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to execute Hive files (.hql) in batch mode with some arguments, like this :

```
hive -hiveconf in_co_societe = 1 in_dt_jour = '2013-01-02 00:00:00.0' -f /home/hduser/Documents/P_THM_CA_RGRP_PRODUITS_JOUR.hql
```

and in my script, i have arguments like this

```
'${hiveconf:in_co_societe}'                                 
'${hiveconf:in_dt_jour}'
```

My script is doing a INSERT INTO...SELECT ... FROM.

When i'm giving arguments, there is nothing imported into destination table.

But, when i write the values directly in the script, everything ok, data are imported.

So, what is wrong with my arguments ?

Thanks,

Comment: Will you be able to edit the question and put the content of the script are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No spaces around the '=', and need a -hiveconf for each variable

```
hive -hiveconf in_co_societe=1 -hiveconf in_dt_jour='2013-01-02 00:00:00.0' 
  -f /home/hduser/Documents/P_THM_CA_RGRP_PRODUITS_JOUR.hql
```

Answer (score 0):

query=`sudo -u #$sudo_user# -i bsub -I /opt/ibm/biginsights/hive/bin/hive -hiveconf Loop_Param='#StartLoop_Activity_312.$Counter#' -f /opt/site1/data/EDW/Finance/Scripts/hqlFiles/VNDR_ITEM_F/OP_UNION.sql`;echo $query

some example syntax that has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this a process that can be used more generically, Hive allows you to pass in variables using the -hiveconf option

```
hive -hiveconf MY_VAR1=value1 -hiveconf MY_VAR2=value2 -f my_script.hql
```

Inside the HQL file, it is used like this:

```
show databases;
show tables;
set dfs.block.size=${hiveconf:MY_ VAR1};
select * from ${hiveconf:MY_ VAR2}  limit 2;

you can put them within a .sh file and it can be execute as:   

 sh my_script.sh
```